# How to find files NOT containing a defined text and output their names into a file?

Tags: batch-file

I am having an application folder with sub-folders and thousands of files in it. I want to write a batch script which lists all the files which DO NOT contain particular text, say `SAMPLE_TEXT` and redirect output to a file. Please help with the script.

Comment: `find` and `findstr` are your friends. See their help pages (`find /?`, `findstr /?`) and take a special look to their parameter `/v`

Comment: I tried these commands and options, however, I was getting all files in output. I think reason was, it checks line by line.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by http://tobint.com/blog/powershell-selecting-files-that-dont-contain-specified-content/ this powershell worked well for me;

```
Get-ChildItem -include *.sql -recurse | ForEach-Object { if( !( select-string -pattern "USE " -path $_.FullName) ) { $_.FullName}} > FilesMissingUse.txt
```

In my case I was searching for database scripts (.sql files) which were missing "USE " string.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you - launch it in the top level folder.

```
@echo off
(for /r %%a in (*) do find "SAMPLE_TEXT" "%%a" >nul || echo %%a)>file.log
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please explain it a bit. I tried with /v option, but it was not giving me proper output.

Comment: Try Aacini's code which is more efficient.  My answer uses a loop to test each file and the `||` executes the last echo command when the file does not contain the text.

Comment: I tried, but got list of all the files in output file.

Comment: @foxidrive: Vishal is right. `findstr /m "string" *.*` works fine, but `findstr /m /v "string" surprisingly fails.

Comment: @Stephan I realise now that `/v` in Aacini's answer returns all lines that doesn't have `string` in it so it actually functions as it should but it doesn't work to solve this task.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
findstr /S /M /V "SAMPLE_TEXT" *.* > output.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work for this task Antonio because the `/v` will test positive for any other text in the file.

Answer (score 1):

With grep you can use

```
grep -L Font *.pdf > list_of_files.txt
```

The -L switch returns only files that do not contain the string "Font."